# SSH connection using key works only with -i command line

Tags: 16.04, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to use the .ssh/config file to use identityFile I'm sure the syntax of the file is 100% correct as it only contain two lines.

```
host *
IdentityFile /path/to/private/key
```

I tried -vvv and I get this error at the end of the trial

```
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

when i use ssh user@host -i same/private/key it works just fine.

I tried deleting know_hosts and everything else I could.

Comment: because unless you are using the default key name you need to specify it with -i. This is how ssh works.

Comment: I would specify the host, and it may be Host with a cap H

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The name of the file is a custom name and it should work as I'm specifying it in my .ssh/config file (which is the default config file for ssh to read from). and it mentions in the -vvv log that its using that same file I'm using with my -i command, buts still no success with handshake.

if the h or H would be an issue, then I should not see ssh logging that it uses my custom /path/to/private/key

thanks for commenting anyway. I will go ahead and give it a try and change the h to H and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after adding IdentityFIle directive inside my /etc/ssh/ssh_config like the below

```
IdentityFile /path/to/private/key
```

ssh connection established fine